# Hibernate Current Session использование транзакций

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

Привет. Решил заменить метод openSession() в Hibernate на getCurrentSession.
Добавил в файл конфигурации строку

```
<property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
```

Но возникла такая проблема. Я использую Criteria для запросов. На методы get я не открывал раньше транзакции(ибо не нужны они там). А при использовании currentSession выдает ошибку

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: createCriteria is not valid without active transaction
```

Приходится абсолютно все методы оборачивать в транзакции.Как это исправить? Ведь так делать не хорошо совсем??

Comment: вы вручную управляете транзакциями или используете transaction manager?

Comment: session.getTranzaction.beginTranzaction. Так вроде. Ну и tranzaction.commit.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate не может работать без транзакции, поэтому даже в случае операций чтения из БД необходимо открывать новую транзакцию.
В таких ситуациях вы можете открывать транзакции только на чтение (при использовании `transaction manager` нужно просто аннотировать метод с помощью `@Transactional(readOnly = true)`, при ручном управлении транзакциями это сделать сложнее (нужно иметь экземпляр `Connection`-а), но можно установить данный флаг на `Criteria.setReadOnly(true)` перед началом транзакции).
Важно отметить, что установка этого флага не гарантирует выполнение запроса в read-only режиме - все зависит от конкретной реализации БД и драйвера, а в случае с `@Transactional(readOnly = true)` еще и со значением `Propagation` - `readOnly` установится только в случае создания новой транзакции при отсутствии существующей.

> Решил заменить метод openSession() в Hibernate на getCurrentSession.

Вопрос создания новой сессии либо использования существующий в данном случае неважен - открывать транзакцию вам необходимо в любом случае. Вот [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8046662/hibernate-opensession-vs-getcurrentsession)  можно почитать про разницу в обоих случаях.

Comment: Спасибо, но странно, что раньше методы get  работали без транзакций.

Comment: именно criteria работали? например, получение объекта по ключу без транзакции будет работать

Comment: Да criteria. Получал по ключу или все записи из бд. Теперь criteria требует транзакции.